# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Converting circular structure to JSON IN REACT FETCH

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, string-formatting

I'm using this submit function below, trying to throw my content to a variable body and sending it by fetching my api, but it's returning the following error as in the image.
NOTE: I load my data with a useEffect.

```
const handleSubmit = async values => {
        let body = {
            ...values,
        }
        setSubmitted(true);
        //SAVE
        const response = await fetch(config.baseURL + '/bot-api/data/model/1/', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        }).then(res => res.json());
        window.alert(response.message);
        window.alert(JSON.stringify(body));
    }
```

and I'm getting the following error:

[image: ERRO JSON]

Comment: show the full code including useEffect

Comment: What is in your `values`? The circular reference is somewhere in that object.

Comment: It's basically saying that your `values` object has circular references and also contains a `HTMLButtonElement` object. You might be sending the wrong object to this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your object is referencing itself and thus cannot be converted to JSON

Consider the following case:

a = {
x: 'Some value'
};
a.b = a;

A string representation would look somethink like this:

```
'{
  "x":"Some value",
  "b": '{
    "x":"Some value",
    "b":...
  }'
}'
```

This would go on forever ans therefore you can't stringify the object.

Also it seems like you want to stringify a HTML Button Element. This is also not possible.

Comment: Could you please explain further why stringify a HTML element is not possible? Is there a way to allow a HTML element (in my case a ul with many li) to be stringified?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this error in React,
3 days of research and finally I get that I am trying to pass "ref" to JSON.stringify, and there sure was a circular reference.

Every new object in the array has this property `ref: createRef()`
like `{name: 'Name', type: 'text', ref: createRef()}`
and to make an object like this to be a JSON string it is actually a reason for error.

And here comes my love, method `array.map` ,

```
const deleteRefsFromArray = array.map(({ ref, ...rest }) => rest);
```

as a result, we receive a clean object without 3km of text from createRef() function.

Hope my case will be useful to someone.